# not able to revert back to the modern experience for Sharepoint list and libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, modern-document-library, classic-experience

My site collection is in modern experience , i.e all the pages are created in modern view as well as list and libraries open up in modern experience.

As a test I activated the site collection feature **SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience** on my site. The list and library were reverted to classic after I activated this feature.

Now when I deactivated the same feature, my list and libraries dont revert back to modern experience. Anyone faced the same issue?
Is it not possible to revert back to modern experience ?

Also the modern experience appears for those list/lib where I select choose modern experience for list/lib by going in the lib settings. but even the newly created list and lib are getting created in classic exp.

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the local storage and cookie in your browser.

If it does not help, open the browser console (F12) and run the script:

```
document.cookie = "splnu = 1; path=/"
```

Then, refresh the list view.

Comment: Hi, clearing the cache worked for me but when the site is opened in another system the library appears in the classic view only.